# Hibernate - passing an entity as a parameter to an SQL query

Tags: java, hibernate

Suppose I have an Oracle stored procedure of the following form:

```
procedure validate_entity1(p_id number, p_property1 varchar2, p_property2 varchar2);
```

I need to call it from my Java application, so I made an `sql-query` like this:

```
<sql-query name="q1" callable="true">
    <!-- . . . -->
    { call validate_entity1(:id, :property1, :property2) }
</sql-query>
```

And then I create this query and bind all these properties by hand. What I would really want to do is to bind the whole entity, like this:

```
session.createNamedQuery("q1").setEntity("entity1", myEntity1);
```

But it doesn't work. Is it possible to do this somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can map an Entity directly to a stored procedure parameters.
You'll have to pass the parameters one by one.

If you want to invoke a stored procedure and if you have Spring, try this :

I'm invoking the procedure 'rex_datainterface.getfieldtype' and I pass 2 parameters :

- recoType (NUMBER) IN.
- result (CURSOR) OUT.

The result of the stored procedure is a

```
List<RecordsetDTO>
```

Here is the code :

```
    @Component
    public class RexFieldTypeDAO {

    @Resource(name = "REXDataSource")
    private DataSource lyxsrvREXDataSource;

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

public RexFieldTypeDAO() {
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

public RecordSetDTO getFieldTypes(int recoType) {
    RecordSetDTO res;

    GetFieldTypeStoredProcedure proc = new GetFieldTypeStoredProcedure(lyxsrvREXDataSource);
    res = proc.execute(recoType);

    return res;
}

/**
 * Private class used to access Stored Procedure.
 */
private static class GetFieldTypeStoredProcedure extends StoredProcedure {
    private static final String SQL = "rex_datainterface.getfieldtype";

    public GetFieldTypeStoredProcedure(DataSource dataSource) {
        super(dataSource, SQL);
        setFunction(true);
        declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("result", OracleTypes.CURSOR, new RecordSetDTORowMapper()));
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter("recoType", OracleTypes.NUMBER));
        compile();
    }

    public List<RecordSetDTO> execute(int recoType) {
        Map<String, Object> inputs = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        inputs.put("recoType", recoType);
        return (List<RecordSetDTO>)super.execute(inputs).get("result");
    }

}
```

}